# Dynamic table names in stored procedure function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure function to get a name from a table. The trouble is that I want the table name to be passed in as a parameter (there are several different tables I need to use this function with):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getName`(tableName VARCHAR(50), myId INT(11)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)

  begin

  DECLARE myName VARCHAR(50);

  SELECT
    'name' INTO myName
  FROM
    tableName
  WHERE 
    id=myId;

  RETURN myName;

  end
```

This method has an error because it uses the variable name "tableName" instead of the actual value of the variable.

I can work around this problem in a *procedure* by using a `CONCAT` like this:

```
    SET @GetName = CONCAT("
    SELECT
       'name'
    FROM
        ",tableName,"
    WHERE 
        id=",myId,";
    ");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @GetName;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

...but, when I try to do this in a function I get a message saying:

> Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

I tried to use a *procedure* instead, but I couldn't get it to just return a value, like a function does.

So, can anyone see a way to get around this problem. It seems incredibly basic really.

Comment: How about a procedure with an `OUT` or `INOUT` parameter to cover your return value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to buld a SQL statement using identifiers, then you need to use prepared statements; but prepared statements cannot be used in functions. So, you can create a stored procedure with OUT parameter -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getName
 (IN tableName VARCHAR(50), IN myId INT(11), OUT myName VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

  SET @GetName =
    CONCAT('SELECT name INTO @var1 FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE id=', myId);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @GetName;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  SET myName = @var1;
END
```

Using example -

```
SET @tableName = 'tbl';
SET @myId = 1005;
SET @name = NULL;
CALL getName(@tableName, @myId, @name);
SELECT @name;
```

Comment: Hello

I want to make procedure for below nested query.
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `refer_id`
    FROM `hrs_demo_data_references`
    WHERE
    `demo_data_records_id` IN
    (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM `hrs_demo_data_records`
        WHERE
        `table_name` = 'tableName' AND `refer_id` 
        IN
        (
            SELECT `id`
            FROM tableName
            WHERE `company_details_id` = 1
        )
    )
)

In this tableName will be dynamic. Could you help me?