# C# and MySQL - Incorrect Syntax?

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

Suppose I this method from my `MySQLOperations` class:

```
    public bool checkIfRowExists(string tableName, string columnToLookIn, string dataToLookFor)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "Server = " + server + "; Database = " + dbName + "; UID = " + user + "; Password = " + password + ";";
        int isExisting = 0;
        using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tablename WHERE @columnname = @data);", myConnection))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columnname", columnToLookIn);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dataToLookFor);
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    isExisting = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return (isExisting == 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in another class, I created a `MySQLOperations` object.
I called on this method within an if statement: `if(objSQLOperations.checkIfRowExists("tblInventory", "ItemID", txtItemID.Text))`. Let us assume that txtItemID contains a valid 10-digit number. And that in my database, I have a table named `tblInventory` with a column `ItemID`.

My problem is that the statements within my catch block executes, saying there was an error with my SQL syntax. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tblInventory' WHERE 'ItemID' = '11111111111'' at line 1." is popped at a MessageBox when my txtItemID contains the text "1111111111".

I believe my `SELECT EXISTS` statement is correct.

Comment: I'm thinking I can't use parameters for table name or column name. If so, is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use parameters for table or column names.  You'll have to build up the SQL string dynamically by concatenation.

Like:

```
var sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + tablename + 
           " WHERE " + columnNameToLookIn + " = @data);"
using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
```

This of course opens you up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if `tableName` and `columnNameToLookIn` can be user entered.  However if the `tableName` and `columnNameToLookIn` are only set in code as it appears in your example then it is not a problem.

Related:

[use a variable for table name in mysql sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc)

[Dynamic table names in stored procedure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705045/dynamic-table-names-in-stored-procedure-function)