# MySQL function with parameters syntax error

Tags: mysql, regex, function

I'm trying to convert this query to a MySQL function

```
SET @v1 := (
SELECT  count(id) as count
    FROM  article_category
    where  (title like "About Usd")
        or (title like "About Usd-%"  and  title regexp '[0-9]$')
           ); 
INSERT  INTO `article_category`
    (`title`,`meta_data`,`meta_description`)
    VALUES
    ( IF(@v1 <= 0, "About Usd", CONCAT("About Usd","-",@v1) ), 
      "ddddD",
      "ddddddd" );
```

This function should return the next available name so I can use it directly in an insert statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_next_unique_name`(tabel nvarchar(255),naem nvarchar(255)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 SET @dd = SELECT count(id) as count FROM tabel where (title like naem) or (title like (naem+'-%') and title regexp '[0-9]$');
 RETURN (naem+'-'+@dd);
END
```

Comment: You need to use `concat` function inside the stored function as well for `(naem+'-%')` and `RETURN (naem+'-'+@dd);`

Comment: i tried that but still have syntax error
marked under "SELECT"

Comment: did you mean `title like (naem+'-%')` to be wildcard matching or just `=` ?

Comment: wildcard 
check the above insert query it increments a number if the title exist in other records based on count
records would be like 
About Usd
About Usd-1
About Usd-2
About Usd-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be getting an error on the `SET @dd` line.

You can't set values to any variable by assigning a statement.
You have to use [`SELECT .... INTO ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) syntax to set value for a variable.

There are several other errors in your code.
Change them as suggested below:

```
CREATE 
    FUNCTION `get_next_unique_name`( tabel nvarchar(255), naem nvarchar(255) )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(id) INTO _count 
      FROM tabel 
     WHERE ( title LIKE naem ) 
        OR ( title LIKE CONCAT( naem, '-%' ) AND title REGEXP '[0-9]$' );

    RETURN CONCAT( naem, '-', _count );
END;
```

Comment: ok that seem very helpful
im just getting an error after DEFAULT 0; (colon missing) although a semi colon is clearly there.

and another error at return (return is not valid input at this position).
correct DECLATE/DECLARE

Comment: @KhalilAwada: Error was due to spelling mistake in `DECLARE1 but not on `DEFAULT 0`. It should work.

Comment: for other to benefit
apparently mysql doesn't allow dynamic names for tables
so practically the above function will try to select from table `tabel`
which was supposed to be a variable name
however there is a way to do it in stored procedure 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705045/dynamic-table-names-in-stored-procedure-function)