# how to pass dynamic table name into mySQL Procedure with this query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have create procedure and when i pass table name manually then its working fine, but when i pass dynamic table name then it says **dbname.tblname doesn't exist**.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE `lmsonline`.`delProc`(tblName VARCHAR(20),sr INT)    
BEGIN
DELETE FROM tblName WHERE srno=sr; 
SET @num := 0;
UPDATE tblName SET srno = @num := (@num+1);
ALTER TABLE tblName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and to execute i have `CALL delProc('beginner',6);`

Comment: have you tried [prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705045/dynamic-table-names-in-stored-procedure-function)?

Comment: i have no idea to execute multiple queries in prepared statement as well as stored procedure. @Tezla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to use prepared Statements like this.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE `delProc`(tblName VARCHAR(20),sr INT)    
BEGIN
  SET @SQL := CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', tblName,' WHERE srno=',sr);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;      

  SET @num := 0;
  SET @SQL := CONCAT('UPDATE ', tblName,' SET srno = @num := (@num+1)');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;      

  SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tblName,' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;      
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What should i do for this two query ?
        SET num := 0;
 UPDATE tblName SET srno = @num := (@num+1);
 ALTER TABLE tblName AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Comment: I have change my answer. but i dont know why you @num ? you set it always to 0 and then you add 1. so its 1

Comment: By using this query i delete a row from table but i have to keep the sequence as it is. number of rows can be decrease but the sequence will not change like if you delete 2 no row from table which contains 1 2 3 4 then the table keep 1 3 & 4 but i want 1 2 3 that's it  [ Reference] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/auto-increment-after-delete-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [] around your table Name , sometime it may happen that it would be a system table having same name as your table name. e.x. [beginner] .

Thanks.

Comment: Not working it says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[beginner],6)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `lmsonline`.`delProc`(IN tblName VARCHAR(20),sr INT)    
    BEGIN
      SET @SQL := CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', tblName,' WHERE srno=',sr);  
   PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
     EXECUTE stmt3;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
    ...try this way ,if not working check whether table exists or deleted by mistake or else.

    Thanks
```