# Unable to pass table name into MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

As part of an exercise, I am trying to write a MySQL function that accepts a table name as an argument and returns the count of records from that table. My function looks like -

```
DELIMITER //
create function recordCount(tname text)
returns int deterministic
begin
    DECLARE rc int;

    select count(*)
    into rc
    from tname;

    return rc;
  end;
//DELIMITER
```

However, when I call this function like -

```
select recordCount('avengers');
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'db.tname' doesn't exist    0.000 sec
```

I don't understand why the function isn't looking for the table 'avengers'. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Hint:  You need dynamic SQL for this . . . `prepare`, `exec`.

Comment: Table name is successfully passed into the procedure - but you cannot use a parameter as table name in a query (it will not be expanded!).

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705045/dynamic-table-names-in-stored-procedure-function